# Special settings for entries with author annotations

Tags: biblatex

For all entries with author annotations, I would like to print all author names and a title. For all other entries, I would like to abbreviate too many author names with et. al. and also omit the title.

After some trial and error, I found the following solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bib.bib}
    @article{A,
        author       = {A Author and B Buthor and C Cuthor and D Duthor},
        author+an    = {=highlight;1=highlight},
        title        = {Title},
        year         = 2013,
    }

    @article{B,
        author       = {B Buthor and C Cuthor and D Duthor and E Euthor},
        title        = {Title},
        year         = 2013,
    }

    @article{C,
        author       = {C Cuthor and D Duthor and E Euthor and A. Author},
        author+an    = {4=highlight},
        title        = {Title},
        year         = 2013,
    }   
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[style=phys,defernumbers,backend=biber, maxnames=3]{biblatex}

% Highlight selected authors
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{%
    %\iffieldannotation{highlight}{highlight}{other}%
    \ifitemannotation{highlight}%
    {\textbf{#1}}%
    {#1}}%
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{%
    \ifitemannotation{highlight}%
    {\textbf{#1}}%
    {#1}}%
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{%
    \ifitemannotation{highlight}%
    {\textbf{#1}}%
    {#1}}%
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamesuffix}[1]{%
    \ifitemannotation{highlight}%
    {\textbf{#1}}%
    {#1}}%

% Increase maxnames if annotated, otherwise delete title.
\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{begentry}{%
\blx@resolve@annotation@label{author}%
\ifinlistcs{highlight}{abx@annotation@field@author}{\defcounter{maxnames}{99}}{\clearfield{title}}%
}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
    \cite{A, B, C}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

This seems to work, but is it the right way to do it?

Also, this solution requires that I change every `author+an    = {...},` to `author+an    = {=highlight; ...},` in all my bib files (which is not that difficult with `sed`). Is it possible to avoid this?

I know that I can set `maxnames` using the `options` field, but this does not seem to work for the title.

For the case it matters, I have a rather complicated setup using many reference sections, reference contexts, categories, and keywords. This special treatment applies only to one bibliography, which is in its own `refsection`.

Comment: I would have thought about setting `options = {maxnames = 99}` for entries with `authpr+an`, but that would have to be done manually (or maybe automatically with Biber). You could also write an option to delete the title there.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to happen to `C`. As I understand your question you would also like that to show all names, but your solution does not do that?

Comment: @moewe Doing it by hand would be a lot of work as I have about 2000 entries (but I could do it if there is a good reason). How do I show the title for these entries and not for others?

Comment: You could define an option that clears the title. What exactly is your use case? Do you want to highlight one particular author at all times?

Comment: @moewe Yes, entry `C` should look similar to entry `A`. It demonstrates, that I need to add a field annotation for my approach to work.

Comment: I already highlight the the names of about 30 authors. Because of length constraints, I now need to remove the titles from other entries in one bibliography. However, the other entries are still printed with titles in other bibliographies (so I can not delete them from the bib file).